# Data having commas creating problem in json

Tags: php, json

I am developing a web applications where users are allowed to enter some text. To create profile, I am using the text entered by users which is saved in database. Problem is, if the data entered by user contains a comma, it is spoiling my page as a json string can't contain a comma. Is there any encoding function in php for supporting commas in json.

Note:
Am using zend framework's zend encoding function to encode json.

Solved:
I got the solution of this problem, json encoding function of zend framework have some issues with encoding decimal data and comma and that was the reason it was creating problem. I used php's own json encode function.

Comment: Can you provide any more info/context? Commas are perfectly valid in a JSON string, so the problem might be something slightly different than what you're expecting.

Comment: A json string can contain anything. If a comma breaks it, then you're not producing the json correctly. Are you doing the encoding yourself? or using a standard library? json_encode() in PHP has absolutely zero trouble with commas.

Comment: A JSON string *can* contain a comma. I'd guess you're not quoting the string, but can't say for sure as you've not added any code. As @Patrick says, use `json_encode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-encode.php) ?

Works well for me:

```
<?php

$str = "my string.";

$json_str = json_encode($str);

echo $json_str . "\n";
```

Gives:

```
"my string."
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can use any character.

```
$json = json_encode($your_array_or_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that as long as you encapsulate your data with either `'` or `"`, it won't parse the `,` as an actual separator. Use `json_encode()` as `@Patrik MARIE` stated above, and you won't be in the need of manually quoting everything!